# RestSharp list on object returns null object

Tags: restsharp

I'm trying to return an object via RestSharp, which has a list property on it, but the result for the entire object is always null.

The object being retrieved is:

```
public class Favourite {
    public Favourite() {
        Drives = new List<Drive>();
    }

    public int FavouriteId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Drive> Drives { get; set; }
}
```

`Drive` is also a known object, which is being returned fine elsewhere.

The request is being made with:

```
var request = new RestRequest() {
    Resource = "Favourites"
};
var result = Client_Execute<List<Favourite>>(request);
return result;
```

And the JSON coming back is:

```
[{"FavouriteId":2,"Description":"This is my test favourite description.","Name":"Favourite 1","Drives":[]}]
```

And I end up with `result == null`.
If however I remove `public IList<Drive> Drives { get; set; }` from `Favourite`, then I get the correct result back.

Is this a bug with RestSharp, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I had a similar problem but with ICollection<T>. Fixed it by changing the property to List<T> (instead of using interfaces).

Answer (score 0):

Other people also report serialization issues using IList with RestSharp.

You may need to try List instead or make sure that you have RestSharp version >= v104.2 where it is mentioned as a bug fix.

[Bug Fixes: Serialization for classes with IList properties](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/releases/tag/104.2)

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Looks like they've fixed it for serialisation but not deserialisation,https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/201